# inheritance without knowning the original and the extension

Tags: javascript, inheritance, abstraction

I have a function that implements inheritance :

```
function extend(original, extension) {
  for (var key in extension) {
    if (extension.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      original[key] = extension[key];
    }
  }
};
```

I have two litteral objects :

```
var a={/* created dynamically */}
var b={/* created dynamically */}
```

### How to know which is the original as well as the extension ?

then i can  do :

```
extend(a, b) //if a is original & b is extension
```

or

```
extend(b, a) // if b is original & a is extension
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: Sorry:..Q is : How to know which is the original as well as the extension ?

then i can do :

extend(a, b) //if a is original & b is extension
or

extend(b, a) // if b is original & a is extension

Comment: how are you defining "original" and "extension"? All your `extend` method does is extend the first object which is passed to it with the values of the second. There is no implied "correct" ordering; it depends entirely on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want merge two litteral objects